# Can't get numbers from input in view to controller in Angular

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have a problem with sending data to my controller. This is my view

```
<form ng-submit="submitMessage()"> 
                <div class="form-group">
                    <input type="number" class="form-control input-sm" name="id_user" ng-model="messageData.id_user" value={{currentUser.id}} >
                </div>

                <div class="form-group">
                    <input type="number" class="form-control input-sm" name="id_thread" ng-model="messageData.id_thread" value={{messages[0].id_thread}}>
                </div>

                <!-- COMMENT TEXT -->
                <div class="form-group">
                    <input type="text" class="form-control input-lg" name="message" ng-model="messageData.text" placeholder="Write your message">
                </div>

                <!-- SUBMIT BUTTON -->
                <div class="form-group text-right">
                    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary btn-lg submit-btn">Submit</button>
                </div>
            </form>
```

and this is my controller, where I send my data to:

```
angular.module('messageCtrl', []).controller('messageController', function($scope, $http, Message, $stateParams) {
// object to hold all the data for the new comment form
$scope.messageData = {};

//get id from route
var id = $stateParams.id;
// get all the comments first and bind it to the $scope.comments object
// use the function we created in our service
// GET ALL COMMENTS ==================================================
Message.get(id).then(successCallback);
function successCallback(data) {
    $scope.messages = data.data;
}

// function to handle submitting the form
// SAVE A COMMENT =====================================================
$scope.submitMessage = function() {
    // save the comment. pass in comment data from the form
    // use the function we created in our service
    console.log($scope.messageData);
    Message.save($scope.messageData).then(successCallback2, errorCallback);
    function successCallback2(getData) {
        $scope.messages = getData.data;
        Message.get(id).then(successCallback);
    }

    function errorCallback(data) {
        console.log(data);
    }

};



});
```

I have a console.log() in the controller to see what data are being sent and only the text is sent. I am trying to have the first two inputs hidden and have value in them. It's basically sending a comment to a thread, so it contains id of user and id of the thread. I don't want them to be visible, but I need to send them to the controller. When I input the numbers manualy, it works ok, but when I have it in the value="" attribute, I get this error in console:

```
angular.js:3505 The specified value "{{messages[0]['id_thread']}}" is not a valid number. The value must match to the following regular expression: -?(\d+|\d+\.\d+|\.\d+)([eE][-+]?\d+)?
angular.js:3505 The specified value "{{currentUser.id}}" is not a valid number. The value must match to the following regular expression: -?(\d+|\d+\.\d+|\.\d+)([eE][-+]?\d+)?
```

I don't understand it, because when I open dev tools and look at the value, it is there as a number. And when

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you have currentUser.id value at the time controller is initialized, then you can create:
`$scope.messageData = { id_user: currentUser.id };`

or

If it takes some time to load the currentUser value then assign back to the messageData object:
`$scope.messageData.id_user = currentUser.id;`

Finally, remove the value attribute and the error should be gone. You can do the same for the id_thread input.

Comment: ok, so I removed the value attributes. Then upon sending the text value I added required ids in the controller itself. I had user id in localStorage and the thread id was in the URL

Answer (score 0):

I guess you need to get rid of `value={{currentUser.id}}` and `value={{messages[0].id_thread}}`, because `ng-model` sets actual value. And you can set `messageData` with the initial values on controller initialization.